# Extracting columns from previous and next line by pattern matching

Tags: regex, awk

I have the following file : extract_info.txt

```
 ABC
 PNG
 CHNS
```

and to_extractfrom.txt from which I need to retrieve information:

```
 ABC  123 234 TCHSL
 NBV  234 23764 DHG
 CHNS 123 347 CGJKS
 CVS  233 4747 JSHGD
 PNG  122 324 HGH
 SJDH 373 3487 JHG
```

and I am running the following code

```
 while read line
 do
  gene=$(echo $line | awk -F' ' '{print $1}')
  app1=$(awk -v comp1="$gene" '(comp1==$1) {print $1 }' to_extractfrom.txt)
 done < extract_info.txt
```

However my desired output is to extract the information for the column in extract_info.txt from the file to_extractfrom.txt such that I get the first column of the previous line on the right and next line on the left of the pattern matched line i.e for the columns in the first file, I will have the output as :

```
NBV ABC -
SJDH PNG CVS
CVS CHNS NBV
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
awk '
  BEGIN         {prev = "-"}
  NR == FNR     {extract[$1] = 1; next}
  is_match      {print $1, m1, m2; is_match = 0}
  $1 in extract {is_match = 1; m1 = $1; m2 = prev}
  {prev = $1}
' extract_info.txt to_extractfrom.txt
```

```
NBV ABC -
CVS CHNS NBV
SJDH PNG CVS
```

If you must have the output in the same order as the extract_info file, and you use GNU awk, you can do

```
gawk '
    BEGIN         {prev = "-"}
    NR == FNR     {extract[$1] = FNR; next}
    is_match      {output[m1] = $1 FS m1 FS m2; is_match = 0}
    $1 in extract {is_match = 1; m1 = $1; m2 = prev}
    {prev = $1}
    END {
        PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@val_num_asc"
        for (key in extract) print output[key]
    }
' extract_info.txt to_extractfrom.txt
```

```
NBV ABC -
SJDH PNG CVS
CVS CHNS NBV
```

Comment: Can you break this code? Because I have another file where I need to extract information from 4th column from the line before and after the pattern is matched and I can reuse the same code for it.

Comment: Haha sorry Mr.Jackman , I meant could you provide step by step explanation so that I can reuse this code?

Comment: FNR=NR will compare the lines from both the files, we store the column that we need to in an array here it is an array called extract and we store all the values from column 1, is_match is a flag ? to further go into next condition.